# Hangout (chat only) integration in web page - getting started?

Tags: chat, google-plus, google-hangouts

I have searched a bit but haven't found an answer to my (newbie) question.

- I have an intranet web page (well, an app consisting of manymany pages, but technology-wise it's all JSPs/HTML/JS).
- Users are authenticated, so I know who is who, OAuth with Google is possible.

Now here's my question:

- I'd like to display availability icons next to person names (all users have Google mail/chat accounts)
- Ideally, I'd be able to initiate a text chat with that person from there

I have found many bits & pieces but I'm new to the Google APIs, so - is it technically possible and where should I start reading?

Thanks for your time.

Markus

Answer (score 1):

The [Google+ Hangouts API](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/) is for building applications for Hangouts Video Calls and does not support text-based Hangouts. Unfortunately, that means that what you want isn't possible for Hangouts users.

However, for the few users still using Google Talk, there is a [Google Talk API](https://developers.google.com/talk/) that you can explore.