# How to create a Google Hangout button for chat-only?

Tags: google-api, google-hangouts

I added a Google Hangout button to my page following [the instructions](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button#basic_page):

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer>
</script>
<g:hangout
   render="createhangout"
   topic="cpp11"
   hangout_type="moderated"
   invites="[{ id : '74838920', invite_type : 'PROFILE' },
       { id : 'my.email@gmail.com', invite_type : 'EMAIL' }]">
</g:hangout>
```

When I press that button a Video Hangout starts (informaing me I should enable video). I am also not sure if I have the hangout invitee correctly, but I will adress that later.

How to let let a **chat-only window** open on the button press?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at the documentation and there is no way of doing it.
https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.av#gapi.hangout.av.CameraMuteEvent

The only way to do it is to ask the participants to click on the "Turn Camera Off" button on the top once they enter the hangout.

Answer (score 2):

There is an option now:

Use `https://hangouts.google.com/chat/person/profileID`. The profile ID is a unique ID of the user and can be retreived via [People API](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get)

Comment: You can also find your profile id in google plus. For example, mine google profile url is is https://plus.google.com/u/0/101381925233311212296, which tells me that my hanguts profile id is 101381925233311212296.

Putting it all together: https://hangouts.google.com/chat/person/101381925233311212296

Answer (score 1):

I don't think chat/text only functonality is available. Your question has been asked before in more general terms (not specific to Google+ Hangout button):

- [Hangout (chat only) integration in web page - getting started?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870566/hangout-chat-only-integration-in-web-page-getting-started)
- [Can Google Hangouts be used for Text Only Live Chat from my WordPress website?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/hangouts/X4mcrmWgscY)

There's not even a way to disable the video by default.

- [Disable video by default in Google hangout?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/hangouts/I7RVN8RncIk)

I can't find official documentation stating chat only is not possible, but [the tag line for Google Hangout Apps](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/) is: "Some things are better face-to-face." The APIs also suggests video is really the focus for Google Hangouts.

Answer (score -1):

there certainly is a way. if you visit someone's G+ page you will find a hangout-symbol right below their profile - clicking this opens a chat-window, not a videocall. 
https://plus.google.com/u/0/replace_this_with_a_google_id/posts

Comment: The link you provided is dead.